# Using numpy.where() to create a new array

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have 2 arrays `A`, `B`:

`A` has shape `(2, 400)` which are 400 `(x, y)` points

`B` has shape `(1, 400)` which are either 0 or 1 for each of the 400 `(x, y)` points

I want to create a new array `C` such that:

```
If B[i] == 0, C[i] = [10, 10, 10]
If B[i] == 1, C[i] = [20, 20, 20]
```

So the shape of `C` should be (400, 3).

I understand that an efficient way would be to use `np.where()` but I cannot figure out how to do this for a 2D matrix.

Comment: In your problem, A is defined but unused. I recommend you to simplify your question.

Comment: Are the points in `A` relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need np.where, instead, use multiply or matmul since you already have a mask. I did the trick with: `np.matmul(B,np.ones((1,3))*10)+10` or `np.multiply(B,np.ones(3) * 10)+10`